# had dice code but lost it during recovery

Tags: arduino-uno

I had the dice code, but reset and forgot to back the code up, now I need help creating the code again, I can't get the select button to proceed to the loop when pressed here's what I have so far:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
// select the pins used on the LCD panel
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

//used for later
String line2 = "Press Select to roll"; // Scrolling line


// define some values used by the panel and buttons
int lcd_key     = 0;
int adc_key_in  = 0;
#define btnRIGHT  0
#define btnUP     1
#define btnDOWN   2
#define btnLEFT   3
#define btnSELECT 4
#define btnNONE   5

// read the buttons
int read_LCD_buttons()
{
 adc_key_in = analogRead(0);      // read the value from the sensor

 // For V1.0 comment the other threshold and use the one below:

 if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE; // We make this the 1st option for speed reasons since it will be the most likely result
 // For V1.1 us this threshold
 if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT;
 if (adc_key_in < 195)  return btnUP;
 if (adc_key_in < 380)  return btnDOWN;
 if (adc_key_in < 555)  return btnLEFT;
 if (adc_key_in < 790)  return btnSELECT;

 return btnNONE;  // when all others fail, return this...
}

void setup() {
 randomSeed(analogRead(1));
 lcd.begin(16, 2);              // start the library
 lcd.setCursor(3,0);
 lcd.print ("Catan Dice");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Press Select to roll");
}

void loop() {
//local varables 
int buttonState = read_LCD_buttons(); // read the button pad
int lastButtonState = btnNONE; // previous state of the button

//Dice
int DiceOne = random(1,7);
int DiceTwo = random(1,7);

  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
  // if the state has changed, increment the counter
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:

if (btnState == btnSELECT)
  lcd.setCursor (0,4);
  lcd.print(DiceOne);

  }

}
lastButtonState = buttonState;

}
```

can anyone help me plz

Comment: I see you have edited the question and completely changed the sketch. What is the error message this sketch is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

You know that LCD shield buttons are usually multiplexed to the analog pin A0? If I've googled correct schematics, this applies to this one too. Therefore no pin change interrupts nor external interrupts can be used.

Maybe analog comparator module with correct threshold.

Comment: can someone help me with my project, the problem is up top